# Create a string collection from CheckedListBox.CheckedItems using LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, checkedlistbox

I have used the Entity framework to populate a checked list box. I want to get the names of the checked items as a string collection so that they can then be used as a filter for another LINQ query.

I populate the list box like this...

```
_eventTypesCheckedList.DataSource = this._dataContext.tblEventTypes.OrderBy(ev => ev.EventTypeName);
_eventTypesCheckedList.DisplayMember = "EventTypeName";
```

This is how I'm failing to get the string collection...

```
var types = from eType in ((_eventTypesCheckedList.CheckedItems) as IEnumerable< tblEventType > )
            select new string( eType.EventTypeName.ToCharArray() );
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Try `_eventTypesCheckedList.CheckedItems.Cast<tblEventType>()`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek you should put that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your `CheckItems` collection using `.Cast<Type>()` extension method:

```
_eventTypesCheckedList.CheckedItems.Cast<tblEventType>()
```