# Sending checkedListBox.CheckedItems to richTextBox

Tags: c#

I have  a project in which I insert text into a `TextBox` ,the said text becomes an `Item` in a `checkeListBox`. All good until now. By the press of a button I want all the `checked Items` in the `checkedlistBox` to appear written in a `RichTextBox` which is located in another form. I have the second form commands all figured out ...I just can not seem to make the `checkedItems` be sent into the `RichTextBox`.

P.S. : I have several `CheckedListBoxes` which need to be sent to the `RichTextBox` if that has any relevance.

**Update:**

I used

```
List<string> Items = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();`
```

to convert the `checkedListBox1.Items` into a string. But,if I try to write

```
fc.richTextBox1.Text = Items;
```

(fc being my Form1) I get an error saying

> can not convert type "...." to "string"`.

How can I fix this error? Add a variable or something else?

**Second Update :**

The problem is almost solved. The code I used before was not right because I can not convert `richTextBox.Text` which is string to . 
Therefore I used another line o code suggested in the answer. This is the error I received:
[image: Image with the Unhandled Exception]

Thank you guys again! As soon as I find a solution I will update!

Solution from other **Questions** that have not worked :

[First Question I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966614/how-to-get-checkedlistbox-checkeditems-as-a-stringlist)

The thing about this one is that it partially worked. I have it shown at the beginning of my question.

[Second Quesstion I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626107/create-a-string-collection-from-checkedlistbox-checkeditems-using-linq)

Even though this is not strictly related to my code I tried converting it so it would work. I reached a point when It partially worked,but I got the same error shown in the screenshot.

[This Question is from another website](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/361933/passing-listbox-items-to-textbox)

When I started the project I tried working with a `for`too. But The thing is that it goes through the whole list. I have 4 separate `checkedListBoxes` ,not a Single one containing everything. Also each of the boxes has a limit of 10 entries ,meanwhile the 4th one can hold an unlimited number.

I also found several solution from these but which did not have any relevance to my needs.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        if (i <= 10)
            checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(0, textBox1.Text);
        if (i >= 11 && i <= 20)
        {   
          if (checkedListBox2.Items == checkedListBox1.Items)
          {
              checkedListBox2.Items.Clear();
          }
            checkedListBox2.Items.Insert(0, textBox1.Text);
        }
        if (i >= 21 && i <= 30)
            checkedListBox3.Items.Insert(0, textBox1.Text);
        if (i >= 31)
            checkedListBox4.Items.Insert(0, textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
        checkedListBox2.Items.Clear();
        checkedListBox3.Items.Clear();
        checkedListBox4.Items.Clear();
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f3.ShowDialog();
        /*StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string S in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            sb.Append(S + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        fc.richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
         */
        /*
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (object checkedItem in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            {
                sb.Append(checkedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            fc.richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
        */
        fc.richTextBox1.Text = String.Join("\n", checkedListBox1.CheckedItems);
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ab1.ShowDialog();
    }

}

Form2 f2 = new Form2();
Form3 fc = new Form3();
```

**Final Update and Answer to the Question**

The Marked answer is the  **right**  answer to this question out of all the ones I read. The error was appearing because I was using a different `form` for reference in the code ,not the one which contained the `Richtextbox`. It was my mistake for not noticing earlier but at least I learned what causes these `NullException` errors. Sorry for the trouble caused!

Thank you all for your help and time,this project will really help me and I just could not finish it.

Comment: Instead of just telling us you looked (which we could not verify anyways), consider showing us what you *did* find, and explain why it didn't work. See this meta discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283163/removing-phrases-like-i-looked-everywhere-on-the-internet-and-i-did-not-find-an

Comment: Do you have Form variables declared in each class?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I did not want to start the question like that in the first place I just thought that if it got "duplicated" the question would get downvoted and unanswered. Thank you for the link .

Comment: @Maiels As the meta discussion says, if you think you might be seen as a duplicate (perhaps you found some similar SO questions?) then link to them, and explain what didn't work with it. That will (a) pre-empt someone closing as a duplicate and (b) shows us stuff you *already* know doesn't work, so we won't suggest it. It also shows you did your research, positives all around :)

Comment: It is most likely `fc` that is null, where do you get the reference to the other form?

Comment: @chancea From my experience it has nothing to do with the other form. I have always been getting that errors and I fixed them differently every time. I believe the error "parameters" are the ones in the yellow highlight.

Comment: `fc` is _the reference to the other form_ and at some point you need to retrieve that reference in order to get the `richTextBox1`.  If you try and use `fc` before you get the reference you will always get a null reference exception

Comment: You have to learn debugging, if you can't solve a null reference problem at your own.

Comment: Posting it now. It is kinda long (not very ,just that this post is already loaded). The one put in the `comment` I put like that not to lose it in case I try other solutions.

Comment: @Maiels No that is not all the code.  We need to see where `fc` is initialized

Comment: Put it in the last line of the code shown

Comment: Ughhh Nevermind I found it. I`ll explain in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` property of a `RichTextBox` is a `string`.  As you are seeing in your error message it is asking for *just a string* not a `List<string>`.  You need to iterate through your list and add all the lines to the text box.  I would say the easiest way to do this is with `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(string S in Items)
{
    sb.Append(S + Environment.NewLine);
}

fc.richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

as @Spacemancraig suggested in the comments you could also do this from the items directly:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (object checkedItem in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems) {
{
    sb.Append(checkedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}

fc.richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I inserted the code you showed me here and made the necessary changes (almost none at all) but ,maybe I did something wrong, i get this error `'System.Environment' does not contain a definition for 'Newline'` Do I have to declare something? Also,Thank you!

Comment: I thought so. I tried several codes before and they "worked" ( I am not saying this one is wrong just that I get the same error). After I check the Items I want shown  they do not appear in the textbox. Moreover after exit I get this `NullReferenceException was unhandled Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: Perhaps post more code so we can see where the null reference exception is happening

Comment: I will take a screenshot.

Comment: you might want to grab each item and set it to string so... foreach (object checkedItem in checkedListBox.ItemsChecked) {... and then get sb.Append(checkedItem.ToString() +Environment.NewLine);

Comment: I used the code recommended by @Spacemancraig and I got the same error,I just notices that the error is making reference to the Last Items in the CheckedListBox. Maybe it has relevance or not I thought it mattered. also,what do you suggest I do about the null reference exception?

Answer (score 1):

If you want add a list of strings as a text to the richTextBox, you can use `String.Join`:

```
fc.richTextBox1.Text = String.Join("\n",Items);
```